# Add custom 'select' statement to Collection Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, grid

I am working with custom grid. I have a literal value I need to pass to _prepareColumns(). Rather than setting up a custom renderer, I want to just add the literal value to the main collection.

In mysql it would be something like:

```
SELECT *, "my literal value" as "my_column" from some_table;
```

Is there any way I can add this to:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('me/mymod')->getCollection();
```

Else, is there another way I can pass a value from _prepareCollection() to _prepareColumns() without using custom renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('me/mymod')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->columns(
            array(
                new Zend_Db_Expr("\"my literal value\" as `my_column`")
            )
        );
```

If I understand you right - this is way you need.

Hope it's helpfull.